# Custom keymap not restored after reboot

Tags: keyboard, reboot, udev

I've written a custom set of keymaps for a Logitech K400plus to shift the function keys down a row (below) and symlinked the file to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-k400p.hwdb`. It behaves correctly after running `sudo systemd-hwdb update && sudo udevadm trigger`.

However, after I reboot it reverts back to the old mapping. `/etc/udev/hwbd.bin` has a new timestamp so I don't believe it's stale.

Is there some other step needed to make the changes persist between reboots?

```
# /etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-k400p.hwdb
evdev:input:b0003v046Dp404D*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70059=f1
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005a=f2
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005b=f3
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005c=f4
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005d=f5
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005e=f6
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7005f=f7
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70060=f8
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70061=f9
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70062=f10
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70056=f11
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70057=f12
```

I am using 20.04 LTS with the below versions of systemd and udev:

```
nfultz@neal-nuc:~$systemd --version
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.2)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
nfultz@neal-nuc:~$udevadm --version
245
```